# Как удалить слово из vector, которое имеют удвоения букв (C++)

Tags: c++

Мне нужно написать програму которая будет копировать все слова и удалять слова, которое имеет удвоения букв. Не понимаю как мне доступится к словам вектора, чтобы правильно написать это.

Например: `MMy name is Romaan Slabinoga,  I'm from lviv.`

Должно получиться вот так: `name is Slabinoga,  I'm from lviv.`

То есть удалить слова `"MMy"` и `"Romaan"`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    set<string> dictionary;

    // new 
    vector<string> vecOfStr;
    string str;
    //

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("out.txt");
    // open file

    while (getline(fin, str)) {
        // new 
        if (str.size() > 0) {
            vecOfStr.push_back(str);
        }
    }

    for (int q = 0; q < vecOfStr.size(); q++)
    {
        string theCurrentWord = vecOfStr[q];
        for (int i = 0; i <= theCurrentWord.length(); i++) {
            if (theCurrentWord[i] == theCurrentWord[i + 1])
            {
                vecOfStr.erase(vecOfStr.begin() + q); // <-- ошибка здесь
            }
            else
            {
                q++;
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned int vector_size = vecOfStr.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++) {
        cout << vecOfStr[i] << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

Сама ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `vecOfStr.erase(vecOfStr.begin() + q); <- ошибка здесь` какая ошибка?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x005316AE in Lab3_2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0128F000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы нашли две повторяющие буквы в слове:

```
if (theCurrentWord[i] == theCurrentWord[i + 1])
```

то вы удаляете это слово из вектора. И продолжаете проверять это же слово, и если в нем опять будут повторяющие буквы, то вы уже удалите не то слово.

Вам нужно как только вы удалили элемент из вектора, сразу приступать к следующему слову (`break`)

Но тут еще одна проблема будет, если вы удалили слово под индексом `q`, то следующее слово в векторе будет иметь тоже индекс `q`, то есть вы перейдя на `q++` пропустите одно слово, в общем вам надо уменьшать `q`, когда вы удалили слово из вектора.

И максимально не понятно зачем вы пишите:

```
else q++;
```

То есть если рядом стоящие буквы не равны, то вы увеличиваете индекс отвечающий за рассматриваемое слово.

Еще есть ошибка во внутреннем цикле. При `i = 0; i <= theCurrentWord.length()` будет ошибка, выход за пределы массива. В вашем случае нужно идти от `0`, до `theCurrentWord.length() - 1` не включительно.

Может есть еще ошибки, я не запускал ваш код, но сразу скажу, что проще просто сделать новый вектор в который вы будете добавлять нужные вам слова и пропускать ненужные.

Comment: "Проще просто сделать новый вектор в который вы будете добавлять нужные вам слова и пропускать ненужные." 
Можете написать как это сделать, потому что не совсем понимаю как работать с векторами.

Comment: Просто создайте новый вектор, если вы нашли 2 равных символа рядом стоящих, то добавляете слово в новый вектор и обязательно пропускаете это слово т.к. оно уже точно не подходит (используйте `break`)

Comment: Напимал как вы сказали но оно не пушит слово в другой вектор, или я не правильно делаю

Comment: Ну я откуда ж знаю, как вы делаете. Но судя по всему не правильно

Comment: for (int q = 0; q < vecOfStr.size(); q++)
  {
    string theCurrentWord = vecOfStr[q];
    for (int i = 0; i <= theCurrentWord.length()-1; i++) {
      if (theCurrentWord[i] == theCurrentWord[i + 1])
      {
        vecOfNewStr.push_back(theCurrentWord);
        break;
      }
    }

  }

Comment: @Romanslabinoga а в ответе не совсем понятно, что я имел в виду, но в условие внутреннего цикла не включительно идти до `theCurrentWord.length() - 1`

Comment: У меня theCurrentWord = "MMy name is Romaan Slabinoga,  I'm from lviv.". Я проверил. Так как тогда редактировать слова?

Comment: Если у вам есть возможность посмотреть код в редакторе, попробуйте

Comment: @Romanslabinoga если у вас все слова в 1 строчке, то вам надо её разделить на проблемы, точки, запятые и т.д. Это уже отдельный вопрос, можете погуглить в интернете много информации по этому вопросу.